# Rails getting around the edit method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models: Photo and Product. These are associated via has_many and nested in.

In my 'create' action in my product controller I associate all the photos the user uploaded that have not been linked to a product. (I do it this way because photos are added via ajax).

Now on the edit page. I want to add photos. Which would require me to link photos to a product. Before I did that in the create action. But as you know in Rails there is no real edit action. Because of this there is nowhere in my products controller I join the two.

So, how do I get around this?

*P.S. I can't join the two in the photo controller before you ask*

**product controller**

```
  def new 
    Photo.where(:product_id => nil, :user_id => current_user).delete_all
    @product = Product.new
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  def create
  binding.pry
  @product = current_user.products.create(params[:product])
    if @product.save
      Photo.where(:product_id => nil, :user_id => current_user).update_all(:product_id => @product.id) 
      render "show", notice: "Product created!"
    else
      render "new", error: "Error submitting product"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @photo = Photo.new
  end
```

**photo controller**

```
  def create
  @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    respond_to do |format|
      @photo.user_id = current_user.id
      if @photo.save
        format.html {
          render :json => [@photo.to_jq_image].to_json,
          :content_type => 'text/html',
          :layout => false
        }
        format.json { render json: {files: [@photo.to_jq_image]}, status: :created, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: what are you talking about, 'no real edit action'?

Comment: Because the edit action is only really used for the view. There isn't a method (that i know of) like create for edit

Comment: sorry, what? The default seven actions in a RESTful rails controller are index, show, new, create, edit, update and destroy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help if you used the scaffolding at least once to observe a typical rails controller. I'd pay attention to the methods generated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method for that

```
def update
end
```

exists